# Compare Dates With SQLAlchemy One-To-Many Relationships

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

**How do you compare dates for one-to-many SQLAlchemy relationships?**

Basically for my model structure, there is a one to many relationship between Team and Player:

```
class Team(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Team'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    players = db.relationship('Player', backref='team', lazy='dynamic')

class Player(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Player'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    last_match = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    team_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Team.id'))
```

So **I want to find all the recent players of a team past a certain date**, but what I tried did not work:

```
team = Team.query.filter_by(id=some_id).first()
recent_players = team.players.filter(Players.last_match.date() > some_date)
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 0):

Just `recent_players = team.players.filter(Players.last_match > some_date)` should do it.
If you really need to have only `date` part of `datetime`, you can cast it using [sqlalchemy.sql.expression.cast](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.cast):

```
recent_players = team.players.filter(cast(Players.last_match, DATE) > some_date)
```

Comment: Hmm thanks, I will try taking out the date, to see if it works